# Modify all columns in a table to 'not null' no matter what

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple command to modify all columns in a table to not null?

Because now I have to find the name and the type of each column to write something like this:

```
    ALTER TABLE testing CHANGE testing_text testing_text VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL;
    ...
```

and that is a lot of work for me.

Comment: you can make a script (ex: php) that will get the column names and types from information_schema and constructs the queries automatically

Comment: @Stephan I am working in bash. I could do it in bash too indeed. But isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: afaik no ... maybe if you make a stored procedure but that like making the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way is to write your alter statements into a file

```
select
concat('ALTER TABLE ', c.TABLE_NAME, ' CHANGE ', c.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', c.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', c.COLUMN_TYPE, ' NOT NULL;') as alter_statement
into outfile '/tmp/alter.txt'
from information_schema.COLUMNS c
where 
c.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

Then execute the file's content

```
source /tmp/alter.txt
```

and you're done...

Tested it in a playground DB and it worked for me, still you might want to double check the file before executing :)

P.S.: I haven't checked how NULL values are handled. IIRC you have to have a default value? Not sure right now. Please test this before using it.

EDIT 1: To have one statement per table:

```
select
concat('ALTER TABLE ', c.TABLE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(' MODIFY COLUMN ', c.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', c.COLUMN_TYPE, ' NOT NULL')) as alter_statement
from information_schema.COLUMNS c
where 
c.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
group by c.TABLE_NAME
```

EDIT 2:

This one works

```
select concat(alter_statement, ';')
into outfile '/tmp/alter.txt'
from (
select
concat('ALTER TABLE ', c.TABLE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(' CHANGE ', c.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', c.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', c.COLUMN_TYPE, ' NOT NULL')) as alter_statement

from information_schema.COLUMNS c
where 
c.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'playground'
group by c.TABLE_NAME
) sq
```

, but `group_concat()` is limited in length, so you might get syntax errors if you have too many columns in a table. Then you still have the first option from above, or you have a look at [this manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to adjust this command so it has only one alter command for each table? like this: `ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY COLUMN clmn1 BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, MODIFY COLUMN clmn2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL`

Comment: I get syntax errors. Rows like `MODIFY COLUMN`without any column name or type. Thanks for your effort, but I will try to solve this issue by getting the names and types and writing them into a file with bash.

Comment: @Ozkan Updated my answer. Syntax errors shouldn't be too hard to correct. Just have a look in the manual.

Comment: First of all, there's a difference between upvoting and accepting an answer. Upvote if it's useful. And why don't you simply post your syntax errors?

Comment: @Ozkan Updated my answer again. Works now, if you don't have too many columns in a table.

Comment: I have too many columns in a lot of tables :), that's the problem in all probability because sometimes some of the alter commabds on large tables just stops in a random place which gives syntax errors.. This is a much more clear answer. thanks

Comment: @Ozkan Edited my answer again. You can change the limit of `group_concat()`.