# Oracle: Dynamically set all NOT NULL columns in a Table to allow NULL

Tags: oracle, nullable

I have a table with 75+ columns in it.
Almost all of the columns have the NOT NULL constraint.

If do a giant alter table modify statement (with every column in there), I get an error saying something along the lines of "You can't set this field to NULL, because it already is NULL"

I have to do this for several tables, and so would prefer to have a dynamic solution.

Can I dynamically find all of the columns that are NOT NULL, and set them to NULL?

I've seen several similar questions like this, but can't find a solution for Oracle SQL.
[Modify all columns in a table to 'not null' no matter what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764737/modify-all-columns-in-a-table-to-not-null-no-matter-what)

Comment: Not sure why you get that message, unless you are trying to change a column to NULLable that is already NULLable.  I just did a test with 4 column table, all columns NOT NULL, and ran alter on all 4 columns to NULL - works fine.  Can you post a small, working sample which re-creates your issue ?  Keep it to a 4 column, 4 row table (that'll be big enough we can see the issue). Include create table, insert, alter scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a test table, with two not null columns, and one null column:

```
create table zzz_mark_test_me (
     cust_id varchar2(20) not null, 
     cust_name varchar2(20) null,  
     cust_phone varchar2(20) not null
);

table ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME created.

desc zzz_mark_test_me

Name       Null     Type         
---------- -------- ------------ 
CUST_ID    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
CUST_NAME           VARCHAR2(20) 
CUST_PHONE NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
```

Now invoke this SQL:

```
select 'alter table ' || table_name || 
    ' modify (' || column_name || ' null );' 
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name='ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME' and nullable='N' 
order by column_id;
```

Which yields this:

```
alter table ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME modify (CUST_ID null );
alter table ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME modify (CUST_PHONE null );
```

Copy/paste the output into SQL*Plus etc. and invoke:

```
alter table ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME modify (CUST_ID null );
table ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME altered.

alter table ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME modify (CUST_PHONE null );
table ZZZ_MARK_TEST_ME altered.
```

And now, no more NOT NULL:

```
desc zzz_mark_test_me
Name       Null Type         
---------- ---- ------------ 
CUST_ID         VARCHAR2(20) 
CUST_NAME       VARCHAR2(20) 
CUST_PHONE      VARCHAR2(20)
```

Comment: I appreciate the mini-tutorial that came with this answer! If you'd like, you could edit it so that the execute immediate statements get in there. Then it's the best of both worlds from yours and Ponder's answers. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this procedure. You can first comment out line containing "execute immediate" to see what it executes, before running. 
First parameter is schema_name, second is table_name.

```
create or replace procedure proc_null(t_owner in varchar2, t_name in varchar2) as 
  v_exec_imm varchar2(1000);
begin
  for o in (select owner, column_name from all_tab_cols where owner=t_owner and table_name=t_name and nullable = 'N')
  loop
    v_exec_imm := 'alter table '||t_owner||'.'||t_name||' modify ('||o.column_name||' null) ';
    execute immediate v_exec_imm;  -- comment this line if You want, modifies table
    dbms_output.put_line( v_exec_imm );
  end loop;
end proc_null;
```

Comment: Of course this is nothing more than @Mark Stewart wrote, but I prepared this solution simultaneously and using procedure you avoid all these copy/pasting.

Comment: Yeah, I am lazy and can never remember the PL/SQL syntax for execute immediate; and I also like seeing what gets generated before it executes.   :)